# Can I visit Dazaifu with a Fukuoka Tourist city pass?

Tags: public-transport, japan, fukuoka

I'm not sure wether the Dazaifu temple is considered to be inside the city limits and accessible with the tourist pass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two versions of the Fukuoka Tourist City Pass. From the [official website](https://yokanavi.com/en/tourist-city-pass/):

> 1. Fukuoka City（not applicable to Nishitetsu Train）: Adult 820 yen, Child 410 yen
> 2. Fukuoka City and Dazaifu: Adult 1,340 yen, Child 670 yen

So the more expensive one will include the train to Dazaifu. This is also noted in [the brochure](http://www.nishitetsu.jp/docs/en/tourist_pass.pdf) with more details on what trains you can use:

[image]